# como fazer chamada ceil

Tags: php

Como poderia arrumar meu código depois de fazer a contagem printando para mim o valor e depois fazer a divisão do mesmo? Sou iniciante em php.

```
$sql = "SELECT Sum(visitas) AS visitas FROM lp_post";
$visitas_total = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($conexao));

if(mysqli_num_rows($visitas_total) <= 0){
    echo 'Nenhum resultado foi econtrado';
}else{
    $visitas = mysqli_fetch_assoc($visitas_total);
    echo ''; 
}

$visitas_media = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT id FROM lp_post")or die(mysqli_error($conexao));

$linhas = mysqli_num_rows($visitas_media);
if($linhas >= '2'){
    $media = ceil($visitas/$linhas);
}else{

}
```

essa é a linha do erro:

```
$media = ceil($visitas/$linhas);
```

e o meu erro é:

> Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in C:\wamp\www.

Comment: Não entendi a pergunta. se for so imprimir a média, faça `echo $media;` ela não é um array.

Comment: Bom dia muito obrigado.Pois bem eu faço a chamada echo na <strong>visitas, porem não me dar o valor.

Comment: onde está declarada a variável $visitas ?  num trecho aparece numa operação matemática e num outro é tratada como array.. não faz sentido

Comment: O que eu vejo é `$ visitas_total`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `mysqli_fetch_assoc` retorna um `array` de resultados.

[Documentação PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

> (PHP 5)
>
> mysqli_result::fetch_assoc -- mysqli_fetch_assoc — Obtem uma linha do
>   conjunto de resultados como uma matriz associativa

---

O erro que você esta tendo é porque a operação de divisão não suporta `array`, neste caso você teria que fazer a divisão assim:

```
$media = ceil($visitas['visitas']/$linhas);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Jeferson Assis, ok! tudo certinho.Valeu.

Comment: Que isso, estamos aqui para sempre ajudar, da um `upvote` sempre que concordar com a resposta :), abs.